# many to many field error __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sin0t.png)

I'm using the model and I keep running into problems with many to many. At first, I made it without giving an id value, but it seems that the id value is not entered, so when I put the id value directly, the same problem as above occurs. But in the Post model below, the same form of likes is used. Why?

```
from django.db import models
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings 
# from server.apps.user.models import Profile

# Create your models here.
  
class Clothes(models.Model):
  CATEGORYS =[
    (0, '상의'), #상의
    (1, '하의'), #하의
    (2, '아우터'), #아우터
    (3, '신발'), #신발
    (4, '악세사리'), #악세사리
  ]
  category = models.IntegerField(default=0,choices=CATEGORYS)
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  img = models.ImageField(upload_to='main/images/clothes/%Y/%m/%d')
  save = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='Pickitems', blank=True)
  author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  buying = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.id}: {self.category}'
    #pk가 존재하지 않는것 같음. 

# class SavePeople(models.Model):
  

class Post(models.Model):
  main_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='main/images/post/%Y/%m/%d')
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  content = models.TextField()
  private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  clothes = models.ManyToManyField(Clothes,related_name='Clothes')
  likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='Likes', blank=True)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.pk}: {self.title}'
  
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f'/community/'
  #이거 나중에 detail page로 바꿔주세요
  
class Comment(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  content = models.TextField()
  create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return f'({self.author}) {self.post.title} :  {self.content}'
  
class Commu(models.Model):
  COMMU_CHOICES = [
    ('buying', 'buying'), #공동구매
    ('openrun', 'openrun'), #오픈런
    ('question', 'question'), #고민방
  ]
  category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COMMU_CHOICES)
  img = models.ImageField(upload_to='main/images/commu/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  content = models.TextField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.pk}: {self.title}'
  
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f'/community/commu'
```

I added the code  `saves= models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='Save', blank=True)` to the Clothes model to make a save of Clothes in the same way as the likes of the Post model, but an error like the attached picture is displayed. occurred. When I searched, it seemed that the pk value did not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `id` field that you explicitly provided, Django itself creates an `id` field as a primary key for each model if you don't specify one. So, it is not necessary to add it to the model. Kindly remove it through the `Clothes` model and run migration commands.

And it doesn't give in case of `likes` since there is no extra field `id` in `Post` model unlike that of `Clothes`.

> **Note:** Models in Django doesn't require `s` to be added as suffix, as it is automatically done, so you may change `Clothes` to `Cloth`.

Comment: However, if you do so, an error like `"<Clothes: None: 0>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.` occurs. I thought None was the pk value here, so I tried the above. How can I fix this error?